# Spark Streaming: How to load a Pipeline on a Stream?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I am implementing a lambda architecture system for stream processing.

I have no issue creating a Pipeline with GridSearch in Spark Batch:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[data1_indexer, data2_indexer, ..., assembler, logistic_regressor])

paramGrid = (
ParamGridBuilder()
.addGrid(logistic_regressor.regParam, (0.01, 0.1))
.addGrid(logistic_regressor.tol, (1e-5, 1e-6))
...etcetera
).build()

cv = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline,
                estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid,
                evaluator=BinaryClassificationEvaluator(),
                numFolds=4)

pipeline_cv = cv.fit(raw_train_df)
model_fitted = pipeline_cv.getEstimator().fit(raw_validation_df)
model_fitted.write().overwrite().save("pipeline")
```

However, I cant seem to find how to plug the pipeline in the Spark Streaming Process. I am using kafka as the DStream source and my code as of now is as follows:

```
import json
from pyspark.ml import PipelineModel
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
```

from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

```
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
kafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc,  "localhost:2181", "spark-    streaming-consumer", {"kafka_topic": 1})

model = PipelineModel.load('pipeline/')
parsed_stream = kafkaStream.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1]))

CODE MISSING GOES HERE    

ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

and now I need to find someway of doing

Based on the documentation [here](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/twitter_classifier/predict.html)  (even though it looks very very outdated) it seems like your model needs to implement the method [predict](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html?highlight=predict#pyspark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel.predict) to be able to use it on an rdd object (and hopefully on a kafkastream?)

How could I use the pipeline on the Streaming context? The reloaded PipelineModel only seems to implement [transform](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html?highlight=pipelinemodel#pyspark.ml.PipelineModel.transform)

Does that mean the only way to use batch models in a Streaming context is to use pure models ,and no pipelines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to load a Spark Pipeline into spark streaming.

This solution works for Spark v2.0 , as further versions will probably implement a better solution.

The solution I found transforms the streaming RDDs into Dataframes using the `toDF()` method, in which you can then apply the `pipeline.transform` method.

This way of doing things is horribly inefficient though.

```
# we load the required libraries
from pyspark.sql.types import (
        StructType, StringType, StructField, LongType
        )
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils

#we specify the dataframes schema, so spark does not have to do reflections on the data.

pipeline_schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("field1",StringType(),True),
        StructField("field2",StringType(),True),
        StructField("field3", LongType(),True)
 ]
)

#We load the pipeline saved with spark batch
pipeline = PipelineModel.load('/pipeline')

#Setup usual spark context, and spark Streaming Context
sc = spark.sparkContext
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

#On my case I use kafka directKafkaStream as the DStream source
directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, suwanpos[QUEUE_NAME], {"metadata.broker.list": "localhost:9092"})

def handler(req_rdd):
    def process_point(p):
        #here goes the logic to  do after applying the pipeline
        print(p)   
    if req_rdd.count()  > 0:
        #Here is the gist of it, we turn the rdd into a Row, then into a df with the specified schema)
        req_df = req_rdd.map(lambda r: Row(**r)).toDF(schema=pipeline_schema)
        #Now we can apply the transform, yaaay
        pred = pipeline.transform(req_df)
        records = pred.rdd.map(lambda p: process_point(p)).collect()
```

Hope this helps.